# $(\log{x})^{-e^{x}}=\frac{1}{(\log{x})^{e^{x}}}>\frac{1}{(x)^{e^{x}}}$ is right when $x\geq 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

Is the following (for $x\geq 1$) right?
$$(\log{x})^{-e^{x}}=\frac{1}{(\log{x})^{e^{x}}}>\frac{1}{(x)^{e^{x}}}$$
I have thought yes (but I am not so convinced) since $\log{x}<x$ and moreover $x$ and $\log{x}$ are surely positive when $x\geq 1$. Another thing that covinces me that this is eventually true is that $x^{e^x}$ goes to infinity faster than $(\log{x})^{e^{x}}$

Am I right? Thanks in advance for any kind of answer or also only a comment

Comment: What bothers you? Except for $x = 1$ there is nothing wrong with what you wrote.

Comment: @Axel  I am not convinced of tha fact that can I say that $(log(x))^{e^x}<x^{e^{x}}$ if $log{x}<x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for every $a>0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}, a^b = \mathrm{e}^{b \ln(a)} $

Then for $x>1$ we have:

$$x>\log(x)>0$$

Therefore, because $\ln$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$,

$$\forall x>1, \ln(x)> \ln(\log(x))$$

Hence, as $\exp$ is strictly positive on $\mathbb{R}$ we have,

$$\forall x>1, \mathrm{e}^x \ln(x)>\mathrm{e}^x \ln(\log(x))$$

Moreover, $\exp$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ so,

$$\forall x>1, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^x \ln(x)} >\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^x \ln(\log(x))}>0$$

Therefore,

$$\forall x>1, x^{\mathrm{e}^x}>\log(x)^{\mathrm{e}^x} >0$$

And the inverse function $ x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}$ is strictly decreasing on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ therefore,

$$\boxed{\forall x>1, \dfrac{1}{\log(x)^{\mathrm{e}^x}}>\dfrac{1}{x^{\mathrm{e}^x}}} $$

That inequality is not well defined for $x=1$ because $\log(1) = 0$ and $\mathrm{e}^1 \neq 0$ hence $\log(1)^{\mathrm{e}^1} =0$ and you know you cannot divide by $0$.

Comment: Thanks  a lot! One question: $(\log{x})^{-e^{x}}$ is defined for $x\geq 1$ but how it is possible if when $x=1$ I have $0$ at the denominator?

Comment: You're welcome. As long as I am concerned, $\log(x)^{-\mathrm{e}^x}$ is not defined for $x=1$. Simply because you cannot have negative exponents with $0$ (it is the same thing as saying that you cannot divide by $0$)

Comment: If you have seen somewhere that $\log(x)^{-\mathrm{e}^x}$ is well defined for $x=1$, please let me know.

Comment: I think you agree that one cannot write, $0^{-1} = 1/0$ so there is no reason you can write $0^{-\mathrm{e}^1}$, as $\mathrm{e}^1>0$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+%28log%28x%29%29%5E%28-e%5Ex%29

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate+%28log%28x%29%29%5E%28-e%5Ex%29+at+x+%3D+1

Comment: Well there is something I do not understand about the result given by Wolfram Alpha on the domain. But at the same time, WA agrees on the fact it diverges to $\infty$ at $x=1$.

Comment: Exactly this is what I can't understand...if it were defined at $x=1$ why f(1) si not a number?!

Comment: I am not aware of how WA works really. You should ask people who have more expertise on it for that specific question. Sorry, I cannot give you further explanations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Cely You're welcome, glad I could help.