# Discrepancy in Wolfram Alpha for the domain of $(\log{x})^{-e^x}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logarithms, wolfram-alpha

In my question [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4144730/900585) I have discussed in the comments of the domain of $$(\log{x})^{-e^x}$$
In wolfram alpha as matter of fact the domain is $x\geq 1$, but I am not convinced of this fact since when I have $x=1$ it appears $0$ at the denominator, for the reason why $(\log{x})^{-e^x}=\frac{1}{(\log{x})^{e^x}}$.

Can you help me in understanding why in WA I have this kind of strange answer?

Comment: It should be an error, because when evaluate $(\log 1)^{-e^1} $ on WA, it gives me $\infty$.

Comment: Yes and this should be in accordance with the fact that in $x=1$ we don't have a number